# Extract and paste multiple elements from a list of lists generated by strsplit

Tags: r, string, list, sapply, stringr

I am trying to extract and paste together elements of a list of lists generated using strsplit.
For example:

```
cat<-c("X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_009", "X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_008", 
"X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_007", "X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_006", 
"X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_005", "X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_004", 
"X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_003", "X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_002", 
"X0831_d8_f1_2s_wt_8_ROI_001", "X0831_d8_f1_10s_wt_8_ROI_019", 
"X0831_d8_f1_10s_wt_8_ROI_018")
```

I can generate the desired character vector using ldply:

```
mouse<-ldply(strsplit(cat, "_"))
paste(mouse$V4,mouse$V8,sep="_")
```

but was looking for a more elegant method of doing it. Perhaps using sapply or something similar?

I can generate a character vector containing one element:

`sapply(strsplit(cat, "_"), "[[",4 )`

but can't figure out a way to extract both elements (and paste them together).

Comment: Check out [grep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html), specifically `regexpr` and `gregexpr`, they will give you the first instance and the position of all instances respectively. This in conjunction with `substr` is how I do much of this type of work

Comment: if the first string always ends with `s`, you could `gsub(".*_(\\d+s)_.*_(\\d+$)", "\\1_\\2", cat)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example in `plyr` is pretty nice already, but here's how to do it in `sapply`, using an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions):

```
sapply(strsplit(cat, "_"), function(x){paste(x[[4]], x[[8]], sep="_")})
```

The `apply` family, and several other functions can use anonymous functions, where you define them in the call. In this case, we have a function that takes each member of the list (as `x`), and then pastes the `x[[4]]` and `x[[8]]` together.

Comment: Great. Really helpful explanation.